# Using deferred.defer with Python 2.7

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to move my App Engine application to the Python 2.7 runtime.

I'm seeing the traceback below when importing the `google.appengine.ext.deferred` library using SDK version 1.6.5. I have also tried uploading the application and see a similar error in runtime.

Does anyone else use the deferred library with Python 2.7. Has anyone seen a similar problem?

**EDIT**

To answer my own question. My application had its own version of `webapp2` (maybe an old version) removing this and adding `webapp2` to the libraries section of `app.yaml` fixed the problem. Although, I'm not quite sure why as the traceback seems to show the deferred library importing the correct version of `webapp`.

Traceback:
...

```
File ".../units/unitsSchema/styleModel.py", line 30, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import deferred
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from deferred import *
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 266, in <module>
    class TaskHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RequestHandler'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a custom `webapp.py` in your python class path which is shadowing the correct `webapp.py` .

I'm currently using the deferred library with the new Python 2.7 runtime without problem.
I've enabled it in the *[builtins](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Builtin_Handlers)* section of my `app.yaml`:

```
builtins:
  - deferred: on
```

Comment: Thanks, I do have deferred: on in the built-ins section of my app.yaml

Comment: To answer my own question. My application had its own version of `webapp2` (maybe an old version) removing this and adding `webapp2` to the `libraries` section of `app.yaml` fixed the problem. Although, I'm not quite sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue. I've tried lots of methods.
Finally, I solved it. It is the webapp2 version problem. 
There are a webapp2 library in the app.yaml file. Only use this one.
Do Not import the webapp2 from the deps.